# How to select the first column of datasets?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get the first column of dataset to calculate the summary of the data such as mean, median, variance, stdev etc...

This is how I read my csv file

```
wine_data = pd.read_csv('winequality-white.csv')
```

I tried to select the first columns two ways

```
first_col = wine_data[wine_data.columns[0]]
wine_data.iloc[:,0]
```

But I get this whole result

```
0        7;0.27;0.36;20.7;0.045;45;170;1.001;3;0.45;8.8;6
1       6.3;0.3;0.34;1.6;0.049;14;132;0.994;3.3;0.49;9...
2       8.1;0.28;0.4;6.9;0.05;30;97;0.9951;3.26;0.44;1...

4896    5.5;0.29;0.3;1.1;0.022;20;110;0.98869;3.34;0.3...
4897    6;0.21;0.38;0.8;0.02;22;98;0.98941;3.26;0.32;1...
Name: fixed acidity;"volatile acidity";"citric acid";"residual sugar";"chlorides";"free sulfur dioxide";"total sulfur dioxide";"density";"pH";"sulphates";"alcohol";"quality", Length: 4898, dtype: object
```

How can I just select the first columns such as ***7,6.3,8.1,5.5,6.0***.

Comment: I'd suggest you pass `sep=';'` to the `pd.read_csv` part, so that you have distinct columns, then you can select your columns. At the moment, your values are all in a single column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use the following:

```
#to see all columns
df.columns 
#Selecting one column
df['column_name']
#Selecting multiple columns
df[['column_one', 'column_two','column_four', 'column_seven']]
```

Something like this example:
[image: example]

Or if you prefer, you might use the `df.iloc`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
first_col = wind_data.ix[:,0]
```